# Why a empty pandas DatetimeIndex contains string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Using python, here's sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DatetimeIndex([])
b = '2030'
print(b in a)
```

and it's True! i think it should be False, just can't figure it out,
is it a bug? appreciate for the explanation,
many thanks!

i try to search any questions or article about this, but i didn't find anything helpful

Comment: Just wondering what do you expect as a result of `"2023" in some_date_range`? I mean `'2023'` is not a date, it's more like a period or time interval, no?

Comment: @Vitalizzare, yeah you're right, actually in my case, the dataframe including data annually and its index value like datetime(2023, 1, 1), datetime(2022, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 1)...
and i simplify it for the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` operator for an Index runs `get_loc` and returns `False` if any of `KeyError`/`ValueError`/`TypeError` is met else `True`.

In the case of an empty `DatetimeIndex` any valid year returns a valid slice:

```
a.get_loc('2023')
# slice(0, 0, None)
```

I don't know if this should be considered a bug (I would say probably yes) or if the expected behavior is just that any valid datetime is part of an empty DatetimeIndex. Interestingly, other keys correctly return `False`.

```
'X' in a
# False
```

Comment: Did you mean `get_loc` instead of `get_lix`?

Comment: @user2357112 yes thanks! (phone autocorrect...)